# Is there something like ":" I am supposed to feature when coloring a word? (HTML)

Tags: html, css, colors, attributes, paragraph

I am making a paragraph about fruit investments. To make it experienced, I am coloring fruit words depending on their color:

```
<h1> Cantaloupes </h1><br>
<p> Cantaloupes is this type of melon that can be used as a fruit, like for drinking a refresher! 
They are used to make juice. It's this avocado looking fruit that has the outside as a different color.
```

And so on. I want to make a `<script>` attribute with `<style>` inside, so I can color the how so numbers of "cantaloupe" in the passage. How can I use `<style>` inside this, and if I cannot, how can I use `<style>` to paint the "cantaloupe" words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<p>
<span style="color: yellow">Cantaloupes</span> is a type of <span style="color: green">melon</span> that can be used... 
</p>
```